# Delta distribution for compact groups and its derivatives

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a compact group (e.g. $SU(2)$) and $\rho: G \mapsto GL(n)$ a representation of it. Then we can define the delta function

$\delta(g-1)=\sum_{l}\chi_l(g)\chi_l(1) = \sum_l\dim_l(G)\chi_l(g)$

for any group element $g \in G$, where $l$ is the index that runs over all irreducible representation of $G$ and $\chi_l(g)=Tr(\rho_l(g))$ is the character in $l$-th representation. Above equation is Peter-Weil theorem.

What is the $m$-th derivative of the delta function $\delta^{(m)}(g-1)$? Is there also an expression in terms of the characters?

Maybe I would derive the representation operators $\rho_l(g)$ as follows:

$\frac{d}{dg}\rho_l(g) = \lim_{\lambda \mapsto 0} Tr(\frac{\rho_l(\delta g_{\lambda}g)-\rho_l(g)}{\lambda})$

Here I have an infinitesimal group displacement $\delta g_{\lambda}$ for an infinitesimal parameter $\lambda$. Is there a recipe for $m$-fold derivatives?

Comment: Of course, general derivatives of $\delta$ are not conjugation-invariant... but, for example, $\Omega^k\delta$, with $\Omega$ the Casimir operator, have such expressions. Otherwise I don't see anything better than your natural derivative expressions. Can you clarify?

Comment: I mean derivatives of delta functions where as an argument a group is passed.

Comment: (Yes, I did infer that you meant "$\delta$ at $1$ on $G$", though I wouldn't write it as a subtraction. But/and do you really need _all_ derivatives with respect to the universal enveloping algebra, or maybe just invariant ones, etc?)

Comment: I would like to know the all derivatives, not just the invariant ones.